# How to use GKSession with wifi?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

I'm implementing a connection between ios devices by using GameKit's GKSession server and client (I need to send messages back and forth but I wont to differentiate a server).

Anyways, my problem is that I want the connection to be exclusively over wifi, not bluetooth. Here's my code:

```
client = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:nil 
                                          displayName:[[UIDevice currentDevice] name] 
                                          sessionMode:GKSessionModeClient];
        [client setAvailable:YES];
```

client is an instance of GKSession. At this point if I see at the console log the application is complaining about bluetooth not being available. How do I tell GKSession to just use wifi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GKSession and GKSessionDelegate custom implementations works for both bluetooth and WiFi. It checks both for wifi and bluetooth, and choose an appropriate transmission medium. If your iPhone is Jailbroken, then there might be some issues with BlueTooth and possibly that is preventing Gamekit to Work Properly.

Comment: My iPhone is not Jailbroken and what I'm trying to do is to make it work over wifi, I'm not interested in bluetooth in this application. Is the code that I posted enough to make the device look for servers over wifi?

Comment: I am not pretty sure, as I am not on my Mac system , but I guess, it should

Comment: You're right, even though it displays the warnings it still uses wifi. Thanks